# Misunderstood latency of a light loop ! JS

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is a part of a Javascript code that I use to inspect permanently the size of the navigator/device in order to make my website responsive :

```
//max screen size value for interactions with other elements : 

var getMaxSize = 0;

// Screen Inspector (initied on Body Onload) :

function Inspector()
{
    if (window.screen.width == 480)
        {
            getMaxSize = window.screen.width;
        }
    setInterval(function(){Inspector()}, 1000);
}
// rest (...)
```

The Inspector function is just a loop that get the value of the screen size every 1 second (we can't say that the computer did not have enough time to think, right?).
However, after a few seconds, can be 15, my RAM saturates.
Why is it so greedy to get a value and assign it to a variable ? Is the object "window.screen" too slow ?

Comment: You probably want `setTimeout`.

Comment: Why do you want to call this every 1 second? Why do you need to call this more than once?

Comment: More than once in the case of the user changes his device orientation

Comment: Yeah, what elclanrs said. Each time you run it, you're making another copy that'll run as well, so the number of function calls you're making is growing exponentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a function run once every second is pretty intensive and older browsers will probably slow down.

To accomplish what you want you should be using a listener for the `onresize` event like this:

```
window.onresize=Inspector;
```

This will run the `Inspector` function every time the user resizes the window, and wont waste system resources.

Comment: ehh, shouldn't this be `window.onresize=Inspector;`? otherwise you're setting the value of `window.onresize` to the _result_ of the invokation of `Inspector`.

Comment: It's pretty strange for a novice in javascript practice like me, cause in my opinion a listener is a type of loop. So I'm surprized of the difference of reactivity between a listener and a script doing the job of a listener. Is this a problem of compilation ?

Comment: @FlowHoa That I might not be the best at answering, but event listeners use far less resources. Think of it like this, when the window resizes, it checks if anything cares (an event listener) and tells them to run.

Comment: Thank you Sharf. But is it better to call the Onresize object in the Body tag or in the first line of the js script ?

Comment: @FlowHoa It could go either really. Personally I would put it in my js script after the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is really quite gnarly and can be avoided in almost every instance. Instead since Javascript is an event based language, you should have it check the screen size ONLY when it detects the event of a change in view port or screen size or your own custom event that you're waiting on to inspect. Having a interval in a browser is general bad practice...

Also JavaScript has some pretty darn good garbage collection on its own, but you may want to set the interval to a variable and clean it up on every execution of it's delegation just to be sure it's only running once at a time and isn't starting to multiply on-top of itself as well.(Growing exponentially due to recursion)